# Pjax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I am using pjax for loading some html after clicking in a link. I need to send some custom data to the url set on the link:

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:beforeSend', function(event, options) {

    options['data'] = $('.fields-on-fly .form-control').serialize();

     return $.pjax.click(event,'',options);
});
```

So I am using **beforeSend** event to catch the pjax before triggers. My issue comes when trying to continue with the process after injecting the data to options.

I got an error:

```
TypeError: link.tagName is undefined
if (link.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'A')
jquery....8767812 (line 82, col 1)
```

The error is on the return when calling: $.pjax.click

Comment: I googled "pjax" and found [a github page that crashes...](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). What is this library supposed to do?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Pjax is Ajax + PushState which allows you to update url so you have use back button. You can check more info here: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, you only needed to modify the options with the data:

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, options) {

    options.data = $('.fields-on-fly .form-control').serialize();

});
```